# Stripe Customer Null in Test Mode

Tags: stripe-payments

While Stripe is in test mode, the customer field of request payloads is null when the mode is **payment** and not **subscription**. Creating the customers in Stripe before submitting the payment (with test credit cards) also doesn't have any affect on the customer field in payment mode.

Is there any way to get Stripe to include customer ids in the request payloads when using the payment mode with test mode? The assumption seems to be that developers don't need to create accounts for customers only making one time payments and not subscribing to a service but this is not the case for my application.

Using **Subscription Mode** (*customer: cus_PIpLq6wFgjP2W3*)

```
{
  "id": "evt_1OUDgfDcghvJaUoz0kK03Z13",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2022-11-15",
  "created": 1704223901,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_test_a1PGOU8a6sLHxvrBnuFeFArDdcXN8E1rSqeAAfjB6kqVK2sBFOy6dWq4q4",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "after_expiration": null,
      "allow_promotion_codes": null,
      "amount_subtotal": 999,
      "amount_total": 999,
      "automatic_tax": {
        "enabled": false,
        "status": null
      },
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel",
      "client_reference_id": null,
      "client_secret": null,
      "consent": null,
      "consent_collection": null,
      "created": 1704223859,
      "currency": "usd",
      "currency_conversion": null,
      "custom_fields": [
      ],
      "custom_text": {
        "after_submit": null,
        "shipping_address": null,
        "submit": null,
        "terms_of_service_acceptance": null
      },
      "customer": "cus_PIpLq2wFgpP2W3",
      "customer_creation": null,
      "customer_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": "US",
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": "28036",
          "state": null
        },
        "email": "testemail@gmail.com",
        "name": "test1 test2",
        "phone": null,
        "tax_exempt": "none",
        "tax_ids": [
        ]
      },
      "customer_email": null,
      "expires_at": 1704310259,
      "invoice": "in_1OUDgbDcghvJaUozYJCmJyo7",
      "invoice_creation": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "locale": null,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "mode": "subscription",
      "payment_intent": null,
      "payment_link": null,
      "payment_method_collection": null,
      "payment_method_configuration_details": null,
      "payment_method_options": null,
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "payment_status": "paid",
      "phone_number_collection": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "recovered_from": null,
      "setup_intent": null,
      "shipping_address_collection": null,
      "shipping_cost": null,
      "shipping_details": null,
      "shipping_options": [
      ],
      "status": "complete",
      "submit_type": null,
      "subscription": "sub_1OUDgbDcghvJaUozli1YZwLQ",
      "success_url": "http://localhost:3000/login",
      "total_details": {
        "amount_discount": 0,
        "amount_shipping": 0,
        "amount_tax": 0
      },
      "ui_mode": "hosted",
      "url": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "checkout.session.completed"
}
```

Using **Payment Mode**
(*customer: null*)

```
{
  "id": "evt_1OTwhHDcghvJaUozf9VptPDi",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2022-11-15",
  "created": 1704158591,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_test_a1ryh8MDmMh1q8mEgX7kExp4m2Ovx5h2WxbKUNFVK6IQhjMhIXDMLsP3BQ",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "after_expiration": null,
      "allow_promotion_codes": null,
      "amount_subtotal": 2399,
      "amount_total": 2399,
      "automatic_tax": {
        "enabled": false,
        "status": null
      },
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel",
      "client_reference_id": null,
      "client_secret": null,
      "consent": null,
      "consent_collection": null,
      "created": 1704158556,
      "currency": "usd",
      "currency_conversion": null,
      "custom_fields": [
      ],
      "custom_text": {
        "after_submit": null,
        "shipping_address": null,
        "submit": null,
        "terms_of_service_acceptance": null
      },
      "customer": null,
      "customer_creation": null,
      "customer_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": "US",
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": "28036",
          "state": null
        },
        "email": "testemail@gmail.com",
        "name": "Testfirst Testlast",
        "phone": null,
        "tax_exempt": "none",
        "tax_ids": [
        ]
      },
      "customer_email": null,
      "expires_at": 1704244956,
      "invoice": null,
      "invoice_creation": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "locale": null,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "mode": "payment",
      "payment_intent": "pi_3OEmgiDcghvJaUoz1Q1TFagq",
      "payment_link": null,
      "payment_method_collection": null,
      "payment_method_configuration_details": null,
      "payment_method_options": {
      },
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "payment_status": "paid",
      "phone_number_collection": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "recovered_from": null,
      "setup_intent": null,
      "shipping_address_collection": null,
      "shipping_cost": null,
      "shipping_details": null,
      "shipping_options": [
      ],
      "status": "complete",
      "submit_type": null,
      "subscription": null,
      "success_url": "http://localhost:3000/login",
      "total_details": {
        "amount_discount": 0,
        "amount_shipping": 0,
        "amount_tax": 0
      },
      "ui_mode": "hosted",
      "url": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "checkout.session.completed"
}
```

**loadStripe Code**

```
async function handleClick() {
        const stripe = await loadStripe(   'pk_test_2fsdf979sdeUozQvee95j3F88MFXPMFrPGPpjlklmm4Y4oh2Uob7uiRdJCjlkozZIyAayjth3vv3fds898sfe2g'
        )
        const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            lineItems: [
                {
                    price: 'price_10FEPIMIDfsdfozETytrkq2',
                    quantity: 1,
                }
            ],
            mode: 'subscription',
            successUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
            cancelUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/cancel'
        })
    }
```

I'm using a [stripe hosted page](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart) so I don't have as much flexibility to hardcode customer ids into transactions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set `customer_creation="always"` when creating your payment mode Checkout Sessions[1]. By default, the setting is `if_required`. Subscriptions do require a Customer object to function, so Checkout will create a Customer for them. For one time payments, a Customer object is not required so no Customer is created unless you specify `customer_creation="always"`.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer_creation

Comment: That option isn't available for the redirectToCheckout function. The RedirectToCheckoutClientOptions Interface does include a clientReferenceId that may work, at least for testing with a single customer:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------


  /**
   * A unique string to reference the Checkout session.
   * This can be a customer ID, a cart ID, or similar.
   * It is included in the `checkout.session.completed` webhook and can be used to fulfill the purchase.
   */
  clientReferenceId?: string;

Comment: I tried the above. Setting clientReferenceId to a customer ID does not cause the customer id to be included in the request payload

Comment: You can't use those parameters when you're using that client-only Checkout integration that uses `redirectToCheckout` (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client) . If you want to be able to control this and force a Customer to be created you need to use the server-based integration where you create the CheckoutSession directly(https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout). Also, `clientReferenceId` is not related at all here.